# "javax.inject.Inject" is not recognized

Tags: dependency-injection, gradle

I have a simple Gradle project.
I have the following in my build.gradle:

```
compile('javax.inject:javax.inject:1')
```

And I can see the jar in gradle cache. But in both Eclipse and IDEA I get following message

```
Error:(8, 20) java: package javax.inject does not exist
```

The really odd thing is that :build is successful, but there is an IDE message and an error when trying to "run".

I tried creating a Maven project and there I can import "@Inject" just fine.

Comment: Try reimporting the project using gradle wrapper or generating IntelliJ or Eclipse config files (respectively `idea` or `eclipse` plugin)

Comment: What does it mean to re-import using wrapper? I am using "idea" plugin.

Comment: First thing to do is to check whether the generated IntelliJ project has that dependency, and if so, whether it's highlighted in red.

Comment: Opening File-> Project Structure-> Libraries in IDEA magically fixed it, but I am still curious what is the root of this issue and how to fix it in Eclipse. Can I view loaded Gradle libs in Eclipse? Also, would it be a good idea to post this bug to Gradle bug tracker?

Comment: Nevermind - I figured it out. If either of you can post your suggestions as an answer I will accept it. After I fixed the project in IDEA Eclipse would not open it and I had to regenerate ".project" using "gradle eclipse".